# Why is SET deprecated?

Tags: common-lisp, deprecated

I'm curious to learn the reason for this since `set` seems unique. For instance:

```
   (set 'nm 3) ;; set evaluates its first argument, a symbol, has to be quoted
   nm ;; ==> evaluates to 3
   (set 'nm 'nn) ;; assigns nn to the value cell of nm
   nm ;; ==> evaluates to nn
   nn ;; ==> ERROR. no value
   (set nm 3) ;; since nm evaluates to nn ...
   nm ;; evaluates to nn
   nn ;; evaluates to 3
```

To achieve similar behavior, I've only been able to use `setf`:

```
   (setq tu 'ty) ;;
   (symbol-value 'tu) ;; returns ty
   (setq (symbol-value 'tu) 5) ;; ERROR. setq expects a symbol
   (setf (symbol-value tu) 5) ;; has to be unquoted to access the value cell
   tu ;; ==> evaluates to ty
   ty ;; ==> evaluates to 3
```

In other programming languages the reason(s) for demotion are pretty clear: inefficient, bug prone, or insecure come to mind. I wonder what the criteria for deprecation for `set` was at the time. All I've been able to glean from the web is [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Common_Lisp/First_steps/Experienced_tutorial), which is laughable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason `set` is deprecated is that its use can lead to errors when it is used on bound variables (e.g., in functions):

```
(set 'a 10)
==> 10
a
==> 10
(let ((a 1))   ; new lexical binding 
  (set 'a 15)  ; modification of the value slot of the global symbol, not the lexical variable
  a)           ; access the lexical variable
==> 1          ; nope, not 15!
a
==> 15
```

`set` is a legacy function from the times when Lisp was "the language of symbols and lists". Lisp has matured since then; direct operations on symbol slots are relatively rare, and there is no reason to use `set` instead of the more explicit `(setf symbol-value)`.

Comment: Is there any resource that specifies the details for this kind of thing? There has to be documentation somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
(set nm 'nn)   ;; assigns nn to the value cell of nm
nm ;; ==> evaluates to nn
```

This is completely wrong and the main reason why it's deprecated. It's the symbol you get when evaluating `nm` that is bound to `nn`. Unfortunately in your example that is the number `3` and it will signal an error at run time since you cannot use numbers as variables. If you were to write `(setq 3 'nn)` the error can be seen at compile time.

With `set` there is an additional reason. It's very difficult to compile when you don't know what symbol is to be bound and the compiler cannot optimize it.

`Scheme` didn't have automatic quoting either in it's first version and they didn't even have a quoted macro like `setq`. Instead it stated that `set'` would suffice. It's obvious that it didn't since Scheme no longer have `set` but only `define`.

I personally disagree that it should be removed (deprecation results in removal eventually) but like `eval` it should be avoided and only used as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, it just seemed to innocuous to be a bad puppy. Looks like Ole Yella needs to be put down...